# Stream multicast media use Gstreamer and VLC

Tags: android, gstreamer, vlc, multicast, rtp

I am writing an application streaming media file ( H264, fortmat I use now is *.MP4 ). 
I use Gstreamer with pipeline :

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/big_buck_bunny_720p_h264.mp4 ! qtdemux name=d d. ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=3 pt=96 mtu=1024 ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000

And I use the following SDP file to receive stream:

c=IN IP4 224.1.1.1

m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

In PC I can receive the stream and it playback normally.
But now I want to receive that stream in my android mobile device? How can I do that.

I used wireshark to capture packet when I use VLC to start the stream ( not gstreamer ) and I can see a packet called Announcement with protocol SAP/SDP and send to port 9875 and IP 224.2.127.254. I think it is how server send SDP file to client but I don't know how the client ( run VLC to receive stream ) can get that packet and process SDP data.
How can I do that with Gstreamer?

Regards,
VinhLoc

Comment: what soft are you using for client on Android? can you also compile and run on Android or you just want to check if the RTSP will play on Android with some rtsp player?

Comment: hi, I find a solution - that create a http server and put the SDP file in there. Now I can use the SDP file to receive streaming media. But problem now is I just can use that SDP file to receive data in PC - It receive and display video very good. But it seem not works with Android device - I use VLC in android. It can get the SDP file but not display anything

Comment: what about saving the sdp file localy and provide to vlc like `vlc file.sdp` ? I am not sure if the androids vlc is capable of this..